# Entity Framework one to many relationship, migration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Hi I have following entities:

```
public class EntityOne
{

    public int EntityOneID  { get; set; }

    public string Smth { get; set; }

    public string User1Id { get; set; }
    public string User2Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser User1 { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User2 { get; set; }


}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<EntityOne> EntityOnes { get; set; }
}
```

I configured Relationships

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EntityOne>()
    .HasRequired<ApplicationUser>(s => s.User1)
    .WithMany(s => s.EntityOnes)
    .HasForeignKey(s => s.User1Id).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<EntityOne>()
    .HasRequired<ApplicationUser>(s => s.User2)
    .WithMany(s => s.EntityOnes)
    .HasForeignKey(s => s.User2Id).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

When I delete one of ApplcationUser from my entity everything is OK, but if I have 2 Application users, it gives me following error:

```
Schema specified is not valid. Errors: The relationship    'SomeProject.Models.EntityOne_User1' was not loaded because the type 'SomeProject.Models.ApplicationUser' is not available.
```

I want to 2 different users having relation with "EntityOne"

**EDIT: Propably answer:**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<EntityOne> EntityOnes1 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EntityOne> EntityOnes2 { get; set; }
}
```

When I created 2 Collections in ApplicationUser everything works.

Comment: try this change WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have two different relationships associated with same property.

> Navigation properties provide a way to navigate an association between two entity types. Every object can have a navigation property for every relationship in which it participates.

*https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx*